# API controller passed invalid JSON receives null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm using ASP.NET's `ApiController` class to create a Web API.  I find that if I pass invalid JSON, instead of the caller getting a 500, the input parameter is null.  As in, if I pass

```
{ "InputProperty:" "Some Value" }
```

which is clearly not valid, to this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public Dto.OperationOutput Operation(Dto.OperationInput p_input)
{
    return this.BusinessLogic.Operation(p_input);
}
```

I get that `p_input` is `null`.  I'd rather send something back telling the user they didn't POST valid JSON.

In my `WebApiConfig.cs`, I have:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Any ideas? I did see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094314/web-api-jsonmediatypeformatter-accepts-invalid-json-and-passes-null-argument-to), but I believe that's ASP.NET MVC, not ApiController.

Comment: @greetings: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: See [MVC4 Model Validation Server Side in API Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588579/mvc4-model-validation-server-side-in-api-controller), you'll have to implement validation.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** I've made the output from the class a little more specific and changed the status code.  I'd started making these changes and later saw @CodeCaster's second comment.

```
public class ModelStateValidFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Before the action method is invoked, check to see if the model is
    /// valid.
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext p_context)
    {
        if (!p_context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<ErrorPart> errorParts = new List<ErrorPart>();

            foreach (var modelState in p_context.ModelState)
            {
                foreach (var error in modelState.Value.Errors)
                {
                    String message = "The request is not valid; perhaps it is not well-formed.";

                    if (error.Exception != null)
                    {
                        message = error.Exception.Message;
                    }
                    else if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error.ErrorMessage))
                    {
                        message = error.ErrorMessage;
                    }

                    errorParts.Add(
                        new ErrorPart
                        {
                            ErrorMessage = message
                          , Property = modelState.Key
                        }
                    );
                }
            }

            throw new HttpResponseException(
                p_context.Request.CreateResponse<Object>(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                  , new { Errors = errorParts }
                )
            );
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(p_context);
        }
    }
}
```

**original answer:**
Thanks to a pointer from @CodeCaster, I am using the following, and it seems to work:

```
/// <summary>
/// Throws an <c>HttpResponseException</c> if the model state is not valid;
/// with no validation attributes in the model, this will occur when the
/// input is not well-formed.
/// </summary>
public class ModelStateValidFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Before the action method is invoked, check to see if the model is
    /// valid.
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext p_context)
    {
        if (!p_context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("The posted data is not valid; perhaps it is not well-formed.")
                  , ReasonPhrase = "Exception"
                  , StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(p_context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'll want to return more detailed errors (for example if required fields are left `null`) and it's not a server error, but rather a client error. `400 BadRequest` might cover it somewhat.