# How to catch casting error instead of null Web Api

Tags: c#, casting

I have an Api Action defined as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddCountry([FromBody] CountryDto country)
{
    // create the country
}
public class CountryDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the payload below, it gets casted to a CountryDto type.

```
{
  "id": "a05ddfdb-07ba-442b-9dd4-1392adf2ee5c",
  "code": "CA",
  "name": "Canada",
}
```

However, if I enter an invalid value that can't be casted like so

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "code": "CA",
  "name": "Canada",
}
```

The countryDto parameter becomes null due to invalid casting. Is there a way for me to make the casting fail throw an exception instead of silently failing?

Comment: You can check to see if the parameter is null right at the beginning and throw an exception. Or, do you want something fancier?

Comment: you might want look at related posts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224630/api-controller-passed-invalid-json-receives-null

Comment: In fact this is nearly bordering on duplicates of several others

Comment: @DougDawson I was actually wondering if there was a way I could split up up the actual request so I could indicate which specific field was suspect instead of the just saying that a bad request has been made.